# Showing next element in array on button click within a modal

Tags: html, angular

Im trying to show a new question from a quiz within a modal when the next button is clicked. I havent used angular 2 before and so im sure im missing a few trivial parts. i know that questions are accessible from the html as i have displayed them in other ways but i cant get them to show in a modal one by one.

html:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" materialize="modal" [materializeActions]="actions">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div *ngIf="let question of questions[pager.index];">
      <div class="badge badge-info">Question {{pager.index + 1}} of {{questions.length}}.</div>
      <p>{{pager.index + 1}}. <span [innerHTML]="question.text"></span></p>
      <div class="row text-left answers">
        <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
          <div class="answer">
            <label class="">
                <input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelect(answer.text);"/>
                {{answer.text}}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goTo(pager.index + 1);">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `*ngIf` in wrong way, you can add `question` field to your Component and fill it with questions[pager.index] in goTo(index) function.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little different to my original code but this is how i achieved it in the

```
<div *ngIf="pager.index < questions.length">
  <h5 class="flow-text"><span [innerHTML]="questions[pager.index].text"></span></h5>
  <br>
  <div class="row text-left">
    <div class="col s12 m12" *ngFor="let answer of questions[pager.index].answers">
      <div class="answer">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="answer.selected" (change)="onSelect(answer)"/><label class="black-text flow-text"> {{answer.text}} </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="row">
    <div class="col s6 m6"></div>
    <div class="col s6 m6">
      <div *ngIf="pager.index < questions.length - 1">
        <button id="nextButton" class="btn-flat black-text right flow-text" (click)="goTo(pager.index + 1);">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="pager.index == questions.length - 1">
        <button id="nextButton" class="btn-flat black-text right flow-text" (click)="goTo(pager.index + 1);">Finish</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```